Semantic Release Docker failing
I have a Next.js App with a Semantic Release action, which should handle Releases and publish the package to my github registry. today it just started failing because of the following error.  Before, it worked fine. Sometimes, it just failed as there was some type errors - but I checked that, there are no errors in the code, so it should go through just as fine.
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  29 |     
  30 | >>> RUN \
  31 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  32 | >>>   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  33 | >>>   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  34 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  35 | >>>   fi
  36 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo \"Lockfile not found.\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
[2:12:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✘  Failed step "prepare" of plugin "@codedependant/semantic-release-docker"
[2:12:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✘  An error occurred while running semantic-release: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  29 |     
  30 | >>> RUN \
  31 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  32 | >>>   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  33 | >>>   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  34 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  35 | >>>   fi
  36 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo \"Lockfile not found.\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
    at makeError (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Image.build (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/lib/docker/image.js:268:30)
    at async dockerPrepare (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/lib/prepare.js:12:3)
    at async validator (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/normalize.js:36:24)
    at async file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:38:36
    at async file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:32:5
    at async pluginsConfigAccumulator.<computed> [as prepare] (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:87:11)
    at async run (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:202:3) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website',
  command: 'docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'Dockerfile:30\n' +
    '--------------------\n' +
    '  29 |     \n' +
    '  30 | >>> RUN \\\n' +
    '  31 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \\\n' +
    '  32 | >>>   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \\\n' +
    '  33 | >>>   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \\\n' +
    '  34 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \\\n' +
    '  35 | >>>   fi\n' +
    '  36 |     \n' +
    '--------------------\n' +
    'ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo \\"Lockfile not found.\\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false,
  pluginName: '@codedependant/semantic-release-docker'
}
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  29 |     
  30 | >>> RUN \
  31 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  32 | >>>   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  33 | >>>   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  34 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  35 | >>>   fi
  36 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo \"Lockfile not found.\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
    at makeError (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Image.build (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/lib/docker/image.js:268:30)
    at async dockerPrepare (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@codedependant/semantic-release-docker/lib/prepare.js:12:3)
    at async validator (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/normalize.js:36:24)
    at async file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:38:36
    at async file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:32:5
    at async pluginsConfigAccumulator.<computed> [as prepare] (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:87:11)
    at async run (file:///home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:202:3) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website',
  command: 'docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'Dockerfile:30\n' +
    '--------------------\n' +
    '  29 |     \n' +
    '  30 | >>> RUN \\\n' +
    '  31 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \\\n' +
    '  32 | >>>   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \\\n' +
    '  33 | >>>   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \\\n' +
    '  34 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \\\n' +
    '  35 | >>>   fi\n' +
    '  36 |     \n' +
    '--------------------\n' +
    'ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo \\"Lockfile not found.\\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false,
  pluginName: '@codedependant/semantic-release-docker'
}

actually, I did not find anything about that. Before the error appears, the action is stuck some time on this step.
[2:04:13 PM] [semantic-release] [@codedependant/semantic-release-docker] › ℹ  build command: docker build --network=default --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:ee7aa8e0c57deb6f8ef1 --quiet --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0-beta --tag ghcr.io/winterhost/website:1.0.0-beta.7 --build-arg SRC_DIRECTORY=website --build-arg TARGET_PATH=. --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_NAME=website --build-arg NPM_PACKAGE_SCOPE --build-arg CONFIG_NAME=website --build-arg CONFIG_PROJECT=winterhost --build-arg GIT_SHA=e5d2e1555989e834ca24590531a7bfe038ee4674 --build-arg GIT_TAG=v1.0.0-beta.7 -f /home/runner/work/website/website/Dockerfile /home/runner/work/website/website

